# Problema con el MapsActivity de google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Estoy insertando una geolocalización en Android Studio para una app:

```
private void miUbiacion() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        actualizarUbicacion(location);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,15000,0,locListener);
    } `
```

Y no me toma el `locListener` siendo que tengo las librerías importadas de manera correcta

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
```

No sé como solucionarlo, no me deja importarlo ni nada sólo me sale en rojo, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas tardes!
Para conseguir la localización tienes que seguir tres sencillos pasos:

Paso 1: Añadir al build.gradle en las dependencias la siguiente compilación

> *compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'*

Paso 2: Añadir al manifest.xml el permiso de localización

> `*<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>*`

Paso 3: Cuando preguntas por los permisos en tu función miUbicacion(), tienes que quitar el return y añadir la línea que pregunta por los permisos

> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new
>   String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
>           }

Por lo que te quedaría así:

```
*if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {*
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 10000);
    *}*
```

Además puedes añadir esta línea para que te aparezca el botón que te lleva a tu ubicación

> *Map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);*

Comment: exactamente amigo, era el problema con el return que tu mencionas, muchas gracias, ha funcionado perfecto! muy agradecido de sus opiniones..

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas agregar la dependencia de Google Play Services para usar servicios de localización

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un mal entendido, `locListener` no es una clase que importas, es un listener que tienes que crear, es el último parámetro requerido por `requestLocationUpdates()`.

> [requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float
>   minDistance, LocationListener listener)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)) Registrar para las
>   actualizaciones de ubicación usando el proveedor, y un Pending Intent.

Lo que puedes realizar es que tu Activity extienda de `LocationListener`, implementas los métodos requeridos.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
```

y de esta forma hacer referencia a la Activity:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,15000,0,this);
```